# Filter on NSMutableArray with NSPredicate - Return No result

Tags: iphone

I got a NSMutableArray* that looks like below and am trying to use a NSPredicate to filter it to return only those that am interested in base upon there status.

After it execute the result variable is empty so for some reason its not filtering, any ideas?

Thanks

Code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"StatusId == %i", aOrderStatus ];
NSLog(@"%@", [predicate debugDescription]);
NSArray *result = [aOrdersList filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
NSLog(@"getRestaurantOrderList - result: %@", [result debugDescription]);
return [result mutableCopy];
```

aOrdersList array content:

```
{
    StatusId = 0;
    cost = "22.950000762939";
    name = "Pieter Uys";
    number = 0823630937;
    order = "1/4 Chicken - SPICE: L";
    "order detail" = "SPICE: L";
    "order title" = "1/4 Chicken";
    orderNo = 2;
    orderNoDisplay = ORD0000000002;
    quantity = 1;
    restaurant = Nandos;
    time = " 20 min ";
},
{
    StatusId = 0;
    cost = "41.950000762939";
    name = "Pieter Uys";
    number = 0823630937;
    order = "1/4 CHICKEN MEAL - Side: CHIPS, Drink: COKE, SPICE: L";
    "order detail" = "Side: CHIPS, Drink: COKE, SPICE: L";
    "order title" = "1/4 CHICKEN MEAL";
    orderNo = 3;
    orderNoDisplay = ORD0000000003;
    quantity = 1;
    restaurant = Nandos;
    time = " 20:00 ";
},
```

Comment: Are they custom objects or NSDictionaries in your array?

Comment: And do you mean it returns an empty `NSArray` or it returns `nil`?

Comment: NSDictionaries inside NSMutableArray object

Comment: What's `aOrdersList` - is that `null` too?

Answer (score 2):

Do this as Depending upon : aOrderStatus

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(StatusId == %d)", aOrderStatus ];
NSArray *result = [aOrdersList filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
NSLog(@"getRestaurantOrderList - result: %@", [result debugDescription]);
```